# Method inside System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, timer

I have a method in a web server application that runs a few mysql queries every x minutes in the background, I searched a good way to do it and came across the System.Threading.Timer class. I managed to code the method inside and using a log I'm keeping track of it's execution (each query and each exception) but I'm facing a problem that I still cannot understand what's happening, the thing is when the method needs to actually do something (when I have a new record on my application the method will grab it's data and start writing it on my database but it will only do that if at that x minute it runs the data is there otherwise it will just run doing nothing) it stops, there is no exception on either the queries or the thread, I just check the log and at the x minute it should be writing something on it there is simply nothing, something just kills my thread and I can't understand what/why, if anyone can help me I would appreciante (sorry my bad english), here is the code snippet:

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path + @"\log_test.txt")) {
                sw.WriteLineAsync("-------- LOG BEGIN --------" + Environment.NewLine);
                try {
                    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (ev) => {
                        bool sync = await AzureSync.Begin();
                    }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "**** ERROR ****" + Environment.NewLine);
                    sw.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't really get it - is anything at all written at any point? This snippet, who executes it? Somewhere, someone has to spawn this code. Is the "LOG BEGIN" line written at all?

Comment: Consider looping on await Task.Delay(...) instead of the timer.  Forces you to think about a stop condition, that's good.

Comment: You should never do `throw ex`, it overwrites the stack trace. You can do `throw;` instead and it will keep the original stack when it re-throws the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using`statement will close the StreamWriter too quickly.  In fact it will close the StreamWriter right after after the new timer is setup.

So the timer won't be able to write to the log when the timer fires with it coded this way.

You will need to move the `using` statement that setups up `sw` into the autonomous method the timer executes.

This should work better for you.

```
 var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (ev) => {

     using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path + @"\log_test.txt")) {
           sw.WriteLineAsync("-------- LOG BEGIN --------" + Environment.NewLine);
            try {
                bool sync = await AzureSync.Begin();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "**** ERROR ****" + Environment.NewLine);
                sw.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
 }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 120000);   //120000 milliseconds is 2 Minutes
```

Also in setting up the timer I'm not sure that TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2) will work for you.  I believe based on this code example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/thread-timers  that the last parameter is in milliseconds.  So 120000 is what you are looking for.

**Additional Things to Consider**
While the above code will "work" it suffers from a serious issue which @Mukesh eludes to in his answer/suggestion.  If a background process throws an exception it will take down the IIS app pool process and force the web app to recycle.  This is almost never desirable.  And the way the above code is written is such that any exception in the timer proc is gonna cause that to happen since after catching an exception and logging them, it rethrows them.  Serious thought should be given to using a 3rd party background scheduler as mentioned in his answer/suggestion, or at the very least it'd be good ensure that no exception escapes from the timer proc like so:

```
 var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (ev) => {
     try{
          using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path + @"\log_test.txt")) {
                sw.WriteLineAsync("-------- LOG BEGIN --------" + Environment.NewLine);
                 try {
                     bool sync = await AzureSync.Begin();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex) {
                     sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "**** ERROR ****" + Environment.NewLine);
                     sw.WriteLine(ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                 }
             }
      }catch{}; //swallow exception and prevent it from taking down the process/IIS app pool
 }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 120000);   //120000 milliseconds is 2 Minutes
```

Comment: @OfirWinegarten you are totally right.  In a quick look I assumed he was tring to try catch the AzureSync.Begin() call given that it's unlikely that setting the time is going to throw.  But you are right that's now what he has coded.  So my answer may not be of much use.  I'll leave it for him though rather than deleting it just in case it has value for him if he meant to try catch the Azure call.

Comment: The timer does not use the stream, that's correct, but the code executed in the callback by the timer uses the stream. If the stream is disposed prior to the callback being executed, which was the case in the original code, then nothing would ever be written to that stream.

Comment: I will run some tests here with these changes and report it back, it's strange since when I start adding data so the AzureSync.Begin() will in fact do something then the whole thing just stops, no exception..nothing! it's weird

Comment: There's no exception handling at all if the AzureSync.Begin call throws an exception in the original version, the version above, however, has exception handling.

Comment: @user3533910 What it really comes down to is "What are you code do you want to watch over with the try catch?"  If it's the Azure call then you need the using statement in the timer proc as I have shown, if you are trying to catch throws from setting up the timer, then what I have  provided won't help.

Comment: @Onkelborg I totally agree.  My assumption is that the original poster was trying to provide try catch support for the Azure call. I'd certainly want that coverage :-)

Comment: RonC and @Onkelborg you are absolutely right. In the original code, there's no exception handling so the OP doesn't know whats going on. And actually the problem is that the timer doesn't use the stream and it should.

Comment: See my updated answer that changes TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)  to 2000 milliseconds.

Comment: 2 Minutes are 120000 miliseconds, and in any case there's a constructor that accept a `TimeSpan` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7#System_Threading_Timer__ctor_System_Threading_TimerCallback_System_Object_System_TimeSpan_System_TimeSpan_

Comment: FromMinutes(2) works too! I'm still testing here but apparently the method is not stopping anymore when it has to record on the database! I will still wait a couple more minutes but as far as I can see the problem was the using() closing the whole thing, living and learning.

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot! using() was probably doing some weird stuff with the thread.

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving you a advice :).
You should not do background job in web application, In IIS web server, application might go into sleep mode or during worker process recycling your background task will not get executed. Instead of this you can integrate library build specifically to achieve background jobs such as [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/), [FLUENTSCHEDULER](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler) etc. which comes with pretty good dashboard functionality too.

Please see below great article for that matter.
[How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: Actually using IIS web server and I can't even understand why the thread is just stopping without any logging showing the reason, I will read your links, thank you very much

Comment: Would you be kind enough to help me? I'm trying to use hangfire IO and saw some examples of what I need to do, I have:
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("123xyz", () => CloudSync(), "*/15 * * * *");

From what I read this should fire CloudSync() every 15 minutes, but I keep getting an exception "'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: method'" but each tutorial I read it's the same syntax

Comment: You should use 'Cron' helper class to generate cron expression that way you can minimize the chance getting wrong. Please use this expression for your requirement. => "RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("123xyz", () => CloudSync(), Cron.MinuteInterval(15));", i have tested this expression with .NET Core and HangFire v 1.6.17.